# cannot pass id or element to mongoose parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

In MongoDB, using mongoose - I tried to delete an item from  collection by using `findByIdAndDelete()`
It throws an error -

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5f080dd69af4c61774ef447f " at path "_id" for model "Item"
```

My Mongoose Code -

```js
app.post("/del", function (req, res) {
    const delItem = req.body.del;
    console.log(delItem);           // this one provides the exact id.
    Item.findByIdAndDelete(delItem, function (err) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("succesfully Deleted");            
        }
    })
})
```

I tried `find({})`  it gives full data,
but problem is only when i tried to give value to it like

`findById({"_id: delItem})` - it is not working

`findById({"_id: "34324jj43j34"})` - if i enter manually it works,

I changed the content of delItems to one item in it then

`find({item: delItem})` -  not working

`find({item: "item 1"})` - working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `delItem` contains a trailing whitespace which causes this problem: `"5f080dd69af4c61774ef447f "` - it should be `"5f080dd69af4c61774ef447f"`.

You could do a trim on the value to prevent this error:

```
Item.findByIdAndDelete(delItem.trim())...
```